# How do I get a java.reflect.Field value for a property inherited from a Groovy trait?

Tags: grails, reflection, groovy, traits

I'm using Groovy 2.4.3 inside of a Grails web application. I have the following Trait/Class hierarchy declared in it:

```
trait GuidData {
    String Guid
}

class Enrollment implements GuidData {
    String email
}
```

When I execute the following code I get the expected results:

```
Enrollment enrollment = new Enrollment(email: "joe@tester.com", guid: "XXXX")
assert enrollment.properties == ['email':'joe@tester.com', 'guid':'XXXX']
assert enrollment.getProperty("guid") == "XXXX")
Enrollment.getDeclaredField("email") == private java.lang.String Enrollment.email
```

But when I execute the method:

```
Enrollment.getDeclaredField("guid")
```

I get a NoSuchFieldException. If I execute a "getDeclaredMethod()" for the "getEmail" method, I correctly get a java.reflect.Method instance back.

So ... it appears that Groovy properties defined in a trait show as Groovy properties and can be referenced like a property defined within the parent class, but they do NOT reflect as a field with getter/setters in the standard Groovy property pattern. In other words, if the property shows up in the instance call to the getProperties(), I would expect the reflection call to get the Field definition to work as well.

Comment: Do you mean `Enrollment.getDeclaredField("guid")` throws a `NoSuchFieldException`?

Comment: Yes. Enrollment.getDeclaredField("guid") throws a NoSuchFieldException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Groovy documentation on Traits](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_public_fields), specifically on public fields (as Burt noted below, this also applies to properties):

> …in order to avoid the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem), field names are remapped in the implementing class…

It goes on:

> The name of the field depends on the fully qualified name of the trait. All dots (.) in package are replaced with an underscore (_), and the final name includes a double underscore. So if the type of the field is String, the name of the package is my.package, the name of the trait is Foo and the name of the field is bar, in the implementing class, the public field will appear as: `String my_package_Foo__bar`.

So for the `Enrollment` class that implements `GuidData`, it doesn't have a field named `Guid`, it has a field named `GuidData__Guid` (assuming `Enrollment` is not in a package). That's why you're experiencing the `NoSuchFieldException`. This should work:

```
Enrollment.getDeclaredField("GuidData__Guid")
```

The `Enrollment` class does have getters/setters `String getGuid()`, `void setGuid(String arg1)`, and that's how you are able to access it using the regular property accessor or using the regular getter syntax.

Comment: That's not a public field, it's a property. But the fields for properties (e.g. `String foo`) and for declared public fields (e.g. `public String foo`) are similarly renamed

Comment: Duh. My bad, thanks for the clarification @BurtBeckwith

Comment: OK ... that makes sense and works. This make for an interesting conundrum when using reflection to get datatypes for all of the fields in an object that you are handed without knowledge of the class / trait hierarchy that it operates in. I guess you would have to iterate the set of traits/interfaces that the base class implements and synthesize a lookup name for each to get a Field definition. If you have multiple inheritance, then I wonder how you know which one is bound to the property name that shows up the properties() method on the implementing class?

Comment: Thanks, good to know indeed. I used the following to reflectively find a property's field from a trait:
```
domainClass.clazz.getDeclaredFields().find { field -> field.getName().endsWith('__' + propertyName) }
```